# Is $f:M_n(\mathbb{C})\longrightarrow M_n(\mathbb{C})$ continuous?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

I want to know whether this is absurd question or reasonable to ask: Let 
$f:M_n(\mathbb{C})\to M_n(\mathbb{C})$ be given by $f(A)= B$, where $B$ is a diagonal matrix having the same eigenvalues as $A$. Is $f$ continuous?

Comment: It might be better to go to $\mathbb C$, for what will you do if eigenvalues are outside of $\mathbb R$? It also might be better to map into something like $S_n\backslash\mathbb R^n$, where the symmetric group permutes coordinates, since the order shouldn't really matter.

Comment: Dear Sir, I agree I must go to $\mathbb{C}$ but would you please tell me the notation $S_n\setminus\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Maybe it isn't so important. I would recommend searching around here for questions involving the words "do the roots of a polynomial depend continuously on its coefficients?"

Comment: I don't get dear sir.would you please elaborate.

Comment: The main problem is that this is not really a function. There are actually up to $n!$ different matrices $B$. To understand the problem, if $A$ has eigenvalues $1,2$ which is the matrix $B$? $1,2$ on the diagonal or $2,1$ on the diagonal? The choice you make in the order of the eigenvalues matters.

Comment: If you find a "right" way (i.e. consistent way) of always ordering the eigenvalues, the question you ask is exactly what Dylan said.

Comment: absolutely true,I got it.

Comment: The ordering of the roots isn't a issue. The natural setting is to view the set of roots of a degree $n$ polynomial with complex coefficients as an element of the quotient on $\mathbb C^n$ by the group of permutation of the coordinates, quotient which is a well-defined topological space (homeomorphic to $\mathbb C^n$). Then the continuity follows from Rouché's Theorem.

Comment: Note also that eigenvalues must be counted by algebraic multiplicity so that there are always $n$ of them.  The quotient is certainly not homeomorphic to ${\mathbb C}^n$, in fact it is not a manifold (think of what a neighbourhood of $(0,\ldots,0)$ looks like).

Comment: @RobertIsrael. Dear Robert: I think your last comment refers to my previous comment. I suppose you forgot to ping me. I was assuming implicitly that the multiplicities must indeed be taken into account. I tried to prove the homeomorphism $S_n\backslash\mathbb C^n\simeq\mathbb C^n$ [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/121607/660). Thanks in advance for telling me what's wrong.  Please see also Statement (ii) at the top of page 208 [here](http://books.google.fr/books?id=nDgBsOurnAIC&lpg=PA210&hl=fr&pg=PA208#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: @RobertIsrael. Dear Robert: Please see also Theorem 4 p. 10 [here](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=SHC_1953-1954__6__A12_0). - Even if you don't believe in the homeomorphism $S_n\backslash\mathbb C^n\simeq\mathbb C^n$, do you agree that: (a) $X:=S_n\backslash\mathbb C^n$ is a topological space, (b) the multiset of roots of a degree $n$ polynomial defines a point of $X$, (c) this point depends continuously on the polynomial?

Comment: Well frankly I am not able to understand any of last 4 comments :(

Comment: @ Pierre-Yves Gaillard: Sorry, you're right, it is a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to order the eigenvalues so that the function $f$ (as a function into $M_n({\mathbb C})$) is continuous.  Consider the matrices $A(t) = \pmatrix{0 & 1\cr e^{2it} & 0\cr}$.  Note that $A(0) = A(\pi)$.  The eigenvalues are $\pm e^{it}$.  But if you take the eigenvalue that is $1$ at $t=0$ and follow it continuously as $t$ goes from $0$ to $\pi$, it will be $-1$ at $t=\pi$.

Comment: Dear sir,I am not able to understand. Would it be possible to express elaborately?will be very pleased.

Answer (score 2):

I think what's behind the question is this:

Write 
$$
(X-z_1)\cdots(X-z_n)=X^n+c_1X^{n-1}+\cdots+c_n,\qquad(*)
$$
where $X$ is an indeterminate and
$$
z=(z_1,\dots,z_n),\quad c=(c_1,\dots,c_n)\in\mathbb C^n.
$$
For any $z$ there is a unique $c$ satisfying $(*)$.

Moreover, the map  $z\mapsto c$, $\mathbb C^n\to\mathbb C^n$, is polynomial, and induces a continuous map $S_n\backslash\mathbb C^n\to\mathbb C^n$, where $S_n\backslash\mathbb C^n$ is the space of orbits of the symmetric group $S_n$ acting on $\mathbb C^n$ by permuting the coordinates.

Conversely, let $c$ be given. By the Fundamental Theorem of Algebras, there is a $z$ satisfying $(*)$.

Moreover, the $S_n$-orbit $S_nz$ of $z$ is depends only on $c$, and by [Rouché's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem), the map $c\mapsto S_nz$, $\mathbb C^n\to S_n\backslash\mathbb C^n$ is continuous.

Clearly the maps $S_nz\mapsto c$ and $c\mapsto S_nz$ are inverse.

In conclusion, we have a homeomorphism 
$$
S_n\backslash\mathbb C^n\simeq\mathbb C^n.
$$
**EDIT.** What Robert Israel's answer shows is that there is no continuous section to the canonical projection $\mathbb C^n\to S_n\backslash\mathbb C^n$.